# How can I print mathing lines of text files in a directory and it's subdirectories which begin with a number or a dot, using shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I tried using the 'grep' command with a pattern, but it didn't work.
Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ ! $# -eq 1 ]
then echo usage: $0 dir
     exit 1
fi

if [ ! -d $1 ]
then echo "$1 is not a directory\!"
     exit 1
fi

grep -r '^[.0-9].*\t$' $1
```

Let's say I have a file (**sample1**), in **~/Downloads/**

**sample1:**

```
123fghgfhfghgfhgfh
.9
something
45
jhjkhjhgjhjh
```

When I type "./myscript.sh ~/Downloads", I want to view:

```
 123fghgfhfghgfhgfh
.9
45
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this `grep` command:

```
grep -rE '^\.?[0-9]' "$1"
```

Comment: This looks good, but how can I filter out the text files, because in the result also appear some binary files?

Comment: Use: `grep -I -rE '^\.?[0-9]' "$1"` to ignore binary files.

Answer (score 1):

You can use command:

```
grep -I -rE "^[.0-9]" $1
```

or

```
grep --binary-files=without-match -rE "^[.0-9]" $1
```